# Catch app 'ready' event outside the app

Tags: ember.js

I need to run some code after ember application got initialized. I don't want to invoke this code from `App.ready` to avoid **tight coupling**. It would be nice to have something like this:

```
App.on 'ready, -> console.log('do stuff')
```

But it won't work since `Em.Application` object is not subscribable and `ready` isn't really an event despite that docs said so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An other possibility may be to invoke your code from the resolve callback of the application.

```
App.then(function(app) {
  console.log("App is resolved, so it's ready");
});
```

example stolen from @intuitivepixel ;) http://jsbin.com/AdOVala/66/edit

**Edit/Note:**

`App.then()` has been deprecated, see http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_code-then-code-on-ember-application:

> As part of the Ember.DeferredMixin deprecation, using .then on an
>   Ember.Application instance itself has been deprecated.
>
> You can use the ready hook or initializers to defer/advance readiness instead.

Comment: Also nice, I always forget about the fact that `App` is then-able :)

Comment: Yeah, but since I don't know if this is intended to be used as is, or if it is a nice side effect. Anyway both our solution work, so this give the choice :)

Comment: Note: `App.then()` has been deprecated, see [http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_code-then-code-on-ember-application](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_code-then-code-on-ember-application)

Answer (score 6):

A simple way you can achieve this would be to extend your `Application` class with the `Ember.Evented` mixin:

```
App = Ember.Application.createWithMixins(Ember.Evented, {
  ready: function() {
    console.log('App ready');
    this.trigger('appReady');
  }
});
```

And you hook inside the `ready` event inside your app and trigger your custom event using `this.trigger(...)`

At this point you can use `.on(...)` to be notified when the event is triggered.

```
App.on('appReady', function() {
  console.log('App already ready');
});
```

Example [demo](http://jsbin.com/AdOVala/65/edit).

Hope it helps.